# Can one prove $f \leq g \implies \lim\limits_{x \to a} f \leq \lim\limits_{x \to a} g $ directly?

Tags: calculus

The proof I found uses $\epsilon = (l - m)/2$ for $l = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f $ and $m = \lim\limits_{x \to a} g $. They also seem to use the same $\delta$ and they arrived at a contradiction.

Is there a way to prove this directly?

Outline of the proof by **contradiction** to remind the readers on how this statement is usually proved. (mine is a little different from the text, but same idea)

> Choose $\epsilon = (l - m)/2$, then for $\delta = \min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$ we have $|x - a| < \delta \implies l - \epsilon< f < l + \epsilon$ and  $-m - \epsilon< -g < -m + \epsilon$
>
> Adding the inequalities yields $$0 < f - g$$ or $$g < f$$

Comment: Regarding whether what you have is really a proof by contradiction, you may want to take a look at this: http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f \le g$, $h = g - f \ge 0$.  Assuming, $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ both exist,  $L = \lim_{x \to a} h(x)$ exists, and satisfies $L \ge 0$.   To see this, note that for $\epsilon > 0$,  there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies -\epsilon + L < h(x) < L + \epsilon$$

If $L < 0$, taking $\epsilon = |L|$ yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

In order to construct a correct proof, consider the function $h=f-g$. If $\lim f,\lim g$ are well defined at every point (maybe different from $f(a),g(a)$), then $\lim h$ is also well defined. Now we know $h\ge 0$ for all $x$. Then to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} h \ge 0$ you need to prove

$$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, \forall x:|x-a|<\delta,h(x)>-\epsilon$$
But now this is trivially satisfied.

Comment: I made a typo. It should have been $\epsilon = \frac{l - m}{2}$

Comment: No, it would not make any difference. Your goal is to show $l\le m$, not $f<g$(which you know already).

Comment: No I assumed $l > m$, but then I arrived $g < f$. So that must mean $l \leq m$

Comment: Then this is still not a proof you wanted, because it is a proof by contradiction again.

Comment: Mine or yours? Why do you have $|h(x) - 0|$? Why $0$?

Comment: I mean your proof. You want a straightforward proof, not a proof by contradiction, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but the proof i wrote in the OP is to give an outline of the "standard" technique. I don't have a solution for a direct proof, but the nature of my question seeks one.

Comment: I see. I thought this is your "direct" proof.

Comment: Oh I am sorry that I made this confusing. I make an edit right now.

Comment: Sorry but why does $h(x) > - \epsilon$ solves everything?

Comment: You want to show the limit is greater than $0$. So pick up a small neighorhood of $a$. The image of this neighborhood under general $f$ may not be positive, but for the limit to be greater than $0$, it must shrink when the neighborhood is shrinking. Hence you have the proof.